Adding 1 column from another table with multiple lines
I have a SQL Server table that includes invoices and another table that includes the lines of the invoices. I'm trying to grab in the lines ones a Price amount on the line to add to my query. my data looks like this (simplified as there is tens of columns in each table and thousands of lines)
Invoice table:
InvNumber | ShipCost
----------+---------
 1        |  500
 2        |  1000

Invoice_line table:
InvNumber  | Product | GL | Price
-----------+---------+----+------
1          |  ABC    | 2  | 10
1          |   Z     | 1  | 50
2          |   X     | 2  | 15

I need to get a query that will grab the price on the invoice line table based on the GL account and add it to my query so in my example if the GL is 1 I need to have that price added to my query.
I created a query with a LEFT JOIN, but when I use it, it created a line where the price is NULL and another line, so I'm missing a little something
Here's my query:
SELECT DISTINCT
    InvNumber, 
    ShipCost,
    CASE
        WHEN Invoice_line.GL = '1' 
            THEN Invoice_line.Price 
            ELSE NULL
    END AS Price
FROM 
    Invoice
LEFT JOIN 
    Invoice_line ON Invoice.InvNumber = Invoice_line.InvNumber

This is the result that I get now:
InvNumber | ShipCost | Price
----------+----------+-------
 1        |  500     | 50
 1        |  500     | NULL
 2        |  1000    | NULL

Expected result
InvNumber | ShipCost | Price
----------+----------+-------
 1        |  500     | 50
 2        |  1000    | NULL

I tried a SELECT DISTINCT but that didn't change anything.
Also played with different type of JOIN but nothing gave me what I was expecting
Not sure what I'm missing to get the result that I'm looking for

Try to group by InvNumber and ShipCost then include max(Price) as price

on your "on" clause put and GL=1  this assumes an invoice can only have 1 GL entry.  if an invoice can have multiple GL's then you're going to need to do a subquery to get the sum of GL 1 for eahc invoice before the join occurs.

Option 1 (if we can assume there's only 1 GL line per invoice)
SELECT 
    InvNumber, 
    ShipCost,
    Invoice_line.Price AS Price
FROM 
    Invoice
LEFT JOIN  Invoice_line 
  ON Invoice.InvNumber = Invoice_line.InvNumber
 and Invoice_Line.GL = '1'

Option 2  (if an invoice can have multiple lines with GL 1 then we need to sum)
SELECT 
    InvNumber, 
    ShipCost,
    sum(Invoice_line.Price) AS Price
FROM 
    Invoice
LEFT JOIN  Invoice_line 
  ON Invoice.InvNumber = Invoice_line.InvNumber
 and Invoice_Line.GL = '1'
GROUP BY InvNumber, ShipCost

Option 3) we could do an inline select since we're only after 1 field .
SELECT 
    InvNumber, 
    ShipCost,
    (SELECT SUM(coalesce(Invoice_line.Price,0)) P
     FROM Invoice_Line 
     WHERE Invoice.InvNumber = Invoice_line.InvNumber
       and Invoice_Line.GL = '1') as Price
FROM Invoice


Thanks xQbert, perfectly what I was looking for. Option 1 found me a problem that Option 2 fixed

Option 3 had a bug which I've corrected.  it uses correlation to get the sum for each invoice.
